# Как сделать правильно расстояние между li?

Tags: html, css3

Как сделать правильно расстояние между li?

```html
    <div class="menu">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Product</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="images/hello.png" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="">Store</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.row{
  width:100%;
  display:table;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px; /*расстояние между пунктами по ширине*/
}

.menu2 ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px 0; /*расстояние между пунктами по высоте*/
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Product</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href=""><img src="images/hello.png" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Store</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="row">
<hr>
</div>
<div class="menu2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Product</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href=""><img src="images/hello.png" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Store</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: а что это такое расстояние между Product и Strore???

Comment: `display:table` и `float:left` для потомка ...жесть жестяная

Comment: там картинка, поэтому и расстояние.

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;  /* or justify-content: space-around; */
  align-items: center;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Product</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x70?text=HELLO" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Store</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Три вида меню :

1) **псевдо таблицы**

2) **flexbox**

3) **на float** *и требует подключение clexfix что я и сделал*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
  display: table;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.menu ul {
  display: table-row;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu1 {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.menu1 ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
}

.menu1 ul li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.clear,
.clear:before,
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.menu2 {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.menu2 ul {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.menu2 ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="">scills</a></li>
    <li><a href="">portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">appirience</a></li>
    <li><a href="">touch my</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="menu1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="">scills</a></li>
    <li><a href="">portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">appirience</a></li>
    <li><a href="">touch my</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="menu2 clear">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="">scills</a></li>
    <li><a href="">portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">appirience</a></li>
    <li><a href="">touch my</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```